# PostgreSQL JSONB serialization/de-serialization with Entity Framework Core 6 and .NET Core 6

Tags: c#, serialization, entity-framework-core, jsonb, npgsql

I am exploring Microsoft Entity Framework Core 6.0.3 with the .NET 6 framework.

My target database is PostgreSQL - and I'm using `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL` (6.0.3).

I have two classes

```
public class ExtendedData
{
      public List<string> familyMembers { get; set; }
      public List<string> phoneNumbers { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{ 
      public String Id { get; set; }
      public String Name { get; set; }
      public List<ExtendedData> Data { get; set; }
}
```

I wrote following code to retrieve data from the `Employee` table:

```
List<Employee> list = db.Employees.Where(x => x.Id == "1234").ToList();
```

I able to see `list[0].Id`, `list[0].Name` populated as expected. I also able to see `list[0].Data[0]` available.

Problem is I am NOT able to see `list[0].Data[0].familyMembers` and `list[0].Data[0].phoneNumbers`.

Problem is, in PostgreSQL database, `familyMembers` column is actually `Family Members` and `phoneNumbers` is `Phone Numbers`.

`Data` column of `Employee` table is set to `jsonb` column and has the following data:

```
[
    { 
      "Family Members": ["Mother", "Father", "Wife"], 
      "Phone Numbers": ["9998887765", "1123444444"]
    }
]
```

My question is: how do I map `Family Members` property of the `jsonb` column into `familyMembers` array of my C# class?

With my investigation, if I use `familyMembers` property in JSON in database, it works

```
[
    {
        "familyMembers": ["Mother", "Father", "Wife"], 
        "phoneNumbers": ["9998887765", "1123444444"]
    }
]
```

Using `JsonProperty("Family Members")` attribute however didn't work.

```
public class ExtendedData
{ 
      JsonProperty("Family Members") 
      public List<string> familyMembers { get; set; }
...
}
```

Not that - even if it doesn't make sense in this example, `Data` property has to be collection (List type) and `familyMembers` and `phoneNumbers` is a list of strings.

Thanks,
Atul

Comment: try change `JsonProperty("Family Members") ` for `JsonProperty("familyMembers")` and your property is `public List<string> FamilyMembers { get; set; }`

Comment: I already tried JsonPropery - but didn't work.

Comment: Hi @Daniel - when I used  [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonPropertyName("Family Members")] , it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I got hint from https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/json.html?tabs=fluent-api%2Cpoco

I was focusing on **JsonProperty** but looks like another attribute **JsonPropertyName** worked.

```
public class ExtendedData
{
[System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonPropertyName("Family Members")]
      public List<string> familyMembers { get; set; }

[System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonPropertyName("Phone Numbers")]
      public List<string> phoneNumbers { get; set; }
}
```